# addCrumb() doesn't work for me cakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have problem with addCrumb() method it doesn't work for me when I use getCrumbs() everything is fine but with addCrumb() method I don't get anything shown in my view I load HTML helper in my AppView and I did everything by CakePHP book but I still don't get breadcrumb trails this is my code sample:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->getCrumbs('>', [
    'text'=>$this->Html->image('home.png',['alt'=>'Home','height'=>50,'width'=>50]),
    'url'=>['controller'=>'Pages','action'=>'display','home'],
    'escape'=>false
]);
$this->Html->addCrumb('Users','/users');
$this->Html->addCrumb('Add User',['controller'=>'Users','action'=>'add']); ?>
?>
```

Comment: Did you check the html code? Maybe breadcrumb is hidden by another element.

Comment: I don't see breadcrumb in my view I just have Html->link helpers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also got confused looking at cake documentation at first. But later I figured it out.

The order of your code is wrong. First you have to do

```
$this->Html->addCrumb('Users','/users');
$this->Html->addCrumb('Add User',['controller'=>'Users','action'=>'add
```

Then the getCrumbs,

```
echo $this->Html->getCrumbs('>', [
'text'=>$this->Html->image('home.png',['alt'=>'Home','height'=>50,'width'=>50]),
'url'=>['controller'=>'Pages','action'=>'display','home'],
'escape'=>false
]);
```

Comment: Thx man you are right it works I read it from Cake documentation